# Парсер файлов

Tags: html, парсер

Посоветуйте парсер для новичка, чтобы было просто разобрать и заменить переменные. Нужен парсер для файлов!

Мы имеем мой `сайт1`. Имеем `сайт2`. У `сайта2` на сервере есть файлы. Нужно сделать так, чтобы у меня на сайте был поиск по их сайту. И трек с названием, которое мы вводим в поиске у меня, появлялся на `сайте1`. С инфой о весе, исполнителе и так далее.

Comment: скажу сразу - универсального парсера нет. Но под какой то определенный сайт можно заточить.
Для того, что бы парсить, можно использовать регулятрные выражения (хотя некоторые и считают, что для html они не применимы).

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с KoVadim) Нужен самописный парсер. ПО поводу регулярок - без них скорее точно никуда. Единственно если сайт правильно оформлени и можно работать с ним через DOM - что будет элегантнее и быстрее

Comment: что такое DOM? обьясни пожалуйста

Comment: Советую почитать http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model